# What does "tapping into the pocket of sunlight" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This phrase is from the [Home(2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_(2009_film)) documentary and the whole sentence is:

> "Our world's clock now beats to the rhythm of these indefatigable machines tapping into the pocket of sunlight."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the other reference referring to 'pocket of sunlight' you can see it refers to the energy trapped within plants in 'pockets' under the earth and originating from the sun. The 'pocket of sunlight' refers to this trapped energy derived from sunlight.

These flames are also from plants.

A pocket of sunlight.

Pure energy.

The energy of the sun, captured over millions of years by millions of plants more than 100 million years ago.

It's coal.

It's gas.

And, above all, it's oil.

Comment: Thanks, is that phrase (pocket of sunlight) only used in the documentary? and does "tapping into" it mean getting benefit from it?